# Get Paragraph Content

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, pydev

I am a bit confused in getting content of the paragraph tag.

```
<div class="SomeID">
<p>What a voice! </p>
</div>
```

I reached at this point

```
list = soup.find_all("div","SomeID")
```

But how to get the paragraph content.(What a voice!)

The basic problem is to get the content of all paragraph tags from

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.urlopen('http://www.dawn.com/news/1267272/democracys-woes').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
list = soup.find_all("div","comment__body cf")
print list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do it one go with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for p in soup.select("div.SomeID > p"):
    print(p.get_text(strip=True))
```

Or, if you need a single `p` element:

```
soup.select_one("div.SomeID > p").get_text(strip=True)
```

Note that `>` here means the direct parent-child relationship.

Comment: Both are not working. I am updating the question. Kindly take a cursory glance at it.

Comment: @AliMurtaza well, `div.comment__body > p` works for me.

Comment: It is not working: 
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
html = urllib.urlopen('http://www.dawn.com/news/1267272/democracys-woes').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# list = soup.find_all("div","comment__body cf")
# print list

list2 =  soup.select_one("div.comment__body cf > p").get_text(strip=True)
print list2

Comment: @AliMurtaza this is what I execute: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/3df9305351c44b1cc78737675d1ac5b8. The output is in the comments to the gist. Using Python3, btw.

Comment: okay. Thanks a lot. It is working (without .requests). I should update the python.